# Custom Tag Handler (no-body) vs EL Function

Tags: java, el, taglib

I consider custom no-body tags and custom EL functions to be interchangeable.

```
<%-- call your custom tag --%>
<custom:formatSlug properties="${properties}" />

<%-- call your custom EL function --%>
${custom:formatSlug(properties)}
```

Tag:

```
package com.example.taglib.handler;

import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;  
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class FormatSlugTagHandler extends SimpleTagSupport {

  private Properties properties;

  @Override
  public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
    getJspContext().getOut().write("slug-" + properties.getProperty("slug")); 
  }
 
  public void setProperties(Properties properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
  }
}
```

EL Function:

```
package com.example.taglib.function;

import java.util.Properties;

public class ELFormatters {

  public void formatSlug(Properties properties) {
    return "slug-" + properties.getProperty("slug");
  }
}
```

I have been trying to find some information around the benefits and drawbacks of each approach, but have failed to find even subjective opinions that support one over the other.  Perhaps the community can weigh in.

Between a tag handler and an EL function, which is better and/or preferred, and why?  Are there any performance differences between the two?  Other minute differences?

Answer (score 0):

EL functions can be used in tag attributes without making the XML parser to cry.

Real world example:

```xml
<input value="<c:out value="${bean.value}" />" />
```

```xml
<input value="${fn:escapeXml(bean.value)}" />
```